# How to solve 200! In Matlab code?

Tags: matlab, factorial

I can't solve 200! with Matlab. When I use the `factorial` function I get an answer of just `inf`. How can I find this?

Comment: Do you need a precise answer or an approximation?

Comment: Actually I want to compare stirling's approximation and real result use with matlab for my assignment

Answer (score 4):

In R2012a, and later, using the [Symbolic Math toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) and [sym/factorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/factorial.html):

```
factorial(sym(200))
```

which returns the exact value of 200!

```
788657867364790503552363213932185062295135977687173263294742533244359449963403342920304284011984623904177212138919638830257642790242637105061926624952829931113462857270763317237396988943922445621451664240254033291864131227428294853277524242407573903240321257405579568660226031904170324062351700858796178922222789623703897374720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This matches the answer returned by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factorial%5B200%5D).

Answer (score 3):

The factorial of `n` is given exactly by `gamma(n+1)`,  where [`gamma`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gamma.html) is [Euler's gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). The problem is that the actual result in this case exceeds [`realmax`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/realmax.html), so `gamma(201)` outputs `inf`. To solve that, use variable-precision arithmetic (function [`vpa`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html), which is part of the Symbolic Toolbox):

```
>> gamma(vpa(200)+1)
ans =
7.8865786736479050355236321393219*10^374
```

This computes the result with an accuracy of `d` decimal digits, where `d` is set by the function `digits` (thanks to @horchler for reminding me of that). By default that's 32 digits. To increase that number,

```
>> digits(60);
>> gamma(vpa(200, 20)+1)
ans =
7.88657867364790503552363213932185062295135977687173263294743*10^374
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `vpa` with the factorial definition:

```
>> prod(vpa(1:200, 50))
ans =
7.8865786736479050355236321393219*10^374
```

---

A third possibility is to directly use `factorial(vpa(200))`. However, this may not work for old Matlab versions, such as R2010b, in which `factorial` doesn't seem to accept a symbolic input.

Comment: FYI, `factorial(vpa(200))` works in newer versions. You should indicate that the results produced by `vpa` are an approximation and depends on the value of `digits`.

Answer (score 2):

Approximation:

You can find a value using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). It is very accurate for large factorials.

The forumla is

```
ln(n!) = nln(n) - n +O(ln(n))
```

Precise Answer:

Use this function called [fact](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21965-factorial-of-large-numbers--%3E170-). It calculates factorial above 170.

```
Example:

fact(double(200))

Answer: 788657867364790503552363213932185062295135977687173263294742533244359449963403342920304284011984623904177212138919638830257642790242637105061926624952829931113462857270763317237396988943922445621451664240254033291864131227428294853277524242407573903240321257405579568660226031904170324062351700858796178922222789623703897374720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Looking at the code for that `fact` function, it seems like it's nothing more than `sym/factorial`. Since the code appears to be pre-R2012a, I'm guessing that the slightly awkward method used was necessary to evaluate symbolic factorials prior to `sym/factorial` being explicitly exposed.

Comment: You should probably link to the actual formula, not the relationship: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/5/0/0/500c098e6169dfceb28c1a5a89613ded.png